# One to One relationship not working in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, excel-2016

Excel version used: 2016

I have 2 excel sheet (HR1 and HR2) in both sheet I have one common column which is emp id. Emp id ranges between 1 to 50000.

Now I connected both the data with the help of power query and used to use only link and loaded it into data model. After loading both files to data model, I used power pivot to connect relationship between both table. The relationship was showing as 1 to many for some reason and not one to one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9nJF.png)

Now, at first I ignored it and I tried to create the pivot table using 1 column ('Attrition' from HR1) and (Monthly salary from HR2). But I received same answer for both cases, which was ofcourse not true.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScTWv.png)

**This is how I tried to solve based on my not so deep understanding over the relationships:**
I tried searching it over internet and I found very few blogs covering one to one relationship and power pivot and ultimately I was not able to find anything which could give some hint on how to solve it.

In past I had observed that in powerBI while creating one to one relationship bi directional filetering is mandatory on, so I though of creating a bridge table and connect it with both table in a hope that it will act as bi directional relationship and my one to one relationship might work, but again I wasn't able to get the results right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFlTL.png)

Please suggest on how can I do this.

PS:
I know that I can simply use vlookup and combine both table without using the powerquery/powerpivot but I am learing this subject and want to know how to do that using power query/power pivot only. Any suggestions are welcomed. Attaching (gdrive link) the files I have worked and source file.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KrQ47Sep9tPaSxEA_7sY1h6-9hL_dyZT?usp=share_link

Regards,
Kishan

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the relationship between your two tables is technically one-to-one. Unfortunately, unlike in Power BI, one-to-one relationships are not supported in Power Pivot.

That said, in this case the solution is quite straightforward. The first thing to note is that you do not require a bridge table here. The second thing to note is that, since Power Pivot does not support one-to-one relationships, it has to declare one of the tables to be on the 'many' side of the relationship, and the other to be on the 'one' side, even if, as mentioned, that relationship is strictly one-to-one.

However, the table which is chosen to be on the 'many' side of a one-to-one relationship makes a crucial difference. In your case, since the end result is a Pivot Table with values (*MonthlyIncome*) from the *HR_2* table being filtered by a field (*Attrition*) from the *HR_1* table, and since filtering only ever propagates from the 'one' to the 'many' side, it must necessarily be the case that the *HR_1* table lies on the 'one' side of the relationship.

I believe it is always the case that, when defining a relationship via the Create Relationship dialog box, the table you define on the left will become the 'many' side of the relationship, so that is how you should set it up here.

Of course, this is all very good if your Pivot Tables will only ever comprise values from the *HR_2* table being filtered by fields from the *HR_1* table. If you also require the contrary, i.e. values from the *HR_1* table being filtered by fields from the *HR_2* table, then it will not be possible with this set-up. Indeed, if that is the case then I would suggest that you merge the two tables into one larger table within Power Query, which would also resolve the wider issue of your your set-up being largely inappropriate here, in that you should not be creating relationships between two large fact tables.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Anyway, I used merged query and made my life easier. Needless to say the blogs on powerpivot are scant compared to excel/PBI which makes it time consuming for users..